# Factory Pattern using java for input parameter class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have Method which return respected Factory base on behavior it should return respected Factory object. How should I implement this using java?

```
public Object getCurrentBehaviour(Class behavior) {

    //e.g behavior type is entity it should return entity factory

    //if behavior type is VO it should return VO factory

}


class EntiryFactory{
}

class VoFactory{
}
```

Comment: Do your factories have common abstraction with different implementations?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you create 2 bases classes, 1 for entity, 1 for VO.

Example:

```
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {

}

public abstract class AbstractVO {


}
```

Then, use a [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern for each object's Factory

```
public AbstractFactory {

    private AbstractFactory() {}

    public abstract Factory getFactory(Class clazz) {
        if (Entity.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new EntityFactory();
        }

        if (AbstractVO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            return new VOFactory();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using a `Class.isAssignableFrom()` method to say that subclassed classes is assignable from the parent class (which it does, if you understand what I'm trying to say). That's the trick here.

For this, I would make a Factory for each object

```
public abstract Factory<T> {

    public abstract T createObject();
}

public class EntityFactory extends Factory<Entity> {

    public Entity createObject(Class entityClass) {
        try {
            return entityClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class VOFactory extends Factory<AbstractVO> {

    public AbstractVO createObject(Class voClass) {
        try {
            return voClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, getting the object

```
Entity entity = (Entity)AbstractFactory.getFactory(Entity.class).createObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe you are essentially asking how to return the appropriate instance from `getCurrentBehaviour(Class behaviour)`

Since the argument is a `Class` object, you can use `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class c)` to check if the class or interface represented by this `Class` object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified `Class` parameter.

Here goes:

```
public Object getCurrentBehaviour(Class behavior) {

    if(behavior.isAssignableFrom(EntiryFactory.class) {
        // create an instance of EntiryFactory
    }

    else if(behavior.isAssignableFrom(VoFactory.class) {
        // create an instance of VoFactory
    }

    return created_instance;
}
```